# Why is Twilio not sending sms?

Tags: c#, twilio

I tried send a sms via the Twilio Api. But Twilio does not send to me any sms messages. What is wrong?

Reference https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Twilio;
namespace SMS

{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string AccountSid = "myAccountSid";
        string AuthToken = "{{ myAuthToken }}";
        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);


        var sms = twilio.SendSmsMessage("myTwilioNumber", "myGsmNumber", "Test SMS", "");
        // var sms = twilio.SendSmsMessage("+14053350954", "+905xxyyyzzvv", "Test SMS", "");


        Console.WriteLine(sms.Sid);
    }
       }
         }
```

Comment: What are you seeing? An exception? What's the contents of sms?

Comment: Twilio puts it in a queue and will be processed first come first serve basis. So you might want to try waiting

Comment: @Liath There is no any exception or error.

Comment: @user3107343 if you log into Twilo you should be able to see a list of messages in there - is yours listed?

Comment: Have you tried without the `statusCallback` argument? In my code I just use `twilio.SendSmsMessage("myTwilioNumber", "myGsmNumber", "Test SMS");` and it works fine.

Comment: It does not matter when using  twilio.SendSmsMessage("myTwilioNumber", "myGsmNumber", "Test SMS")

Comment: @user3107343 I'm just sanity checking here - I assume you're not actually using the strings "myTwilioNumber" are you?

Comment: One odd behavior i personally experience is that SendSmsMessage doesn't call callbackurl correctly and updates the sms status to delivered. instead SendMessage works correctly

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

Couple of ways to start diagnosing this.

First I'd suggest logging into your account and checking the [message logs](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/messages).  If your app is actually successfully connecting to Twilio and telling it to send the text message, it will show up here.

If there are no messages in the log its likely that there is an error happening when you try to use the REST API to test Twilio to send the message.   To check that you can look at the RestException property on your *sms* variable:

```
if (sms.RestException!=null)
{
    Debug.Writeline(sms.RestException.Message);
}
```

If the RestException parameter is null, then there is likely a transport error happening.  Either your seeing a DNS resolve failure, or an HTTP request timeout.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you expand on transport errors? I have a laptop working through a VPN tunnel that will fail this call - the 'sms' object comes back null after the call. What ports/protocols are required for this to work?

Comment: You communicate through the REST API via an HTTP request.  Transport errors could include things like DNS resolution failures or request timeouts.  Basically stuff that causes the HTTP request to not get a complete response