# Twilio SMS messaging not working in Console Application

Tags: c#, twilio

I funded my Twilio account and am working in a console application. When to go to the documentation (Here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/api-explorer/message-create) and enter my phone number the request works. However, when I copy the code to a local console application nothing happens. I literally copy the code line for line and make sure the SID, Token, and Numbers are correct and nothing happens at all, the console app just runs to the end of execution.

```
string AccountSid = "MySID";
string AuthToken = "MyAuthToken";
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
var message = twilio.SendSmsMessage("+12222222222", "+13333333333","Hello World");
Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
```

I run Fiddler and I get this for the Raw Packet. Also Fiddler says the result is a 401 status code.

POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/MySID/SMS/Messages.json HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic {TonsOfRandomCharactersThatLookLikeISHouldHide}
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
Accept-charset: utf-8
User-Agent: twilio-csharp/3.4.1.0 (.NET 4.0.30319.17929)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: api.twilio.com
Content-Length: 56
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

From=%2B14697891380&To=%2B12146630105&Body=New%20Message

Any ideas on what could be going one? I know others are having this issue, I see it posted in other places, but I have yet to see a response.

Also here is a link to another person having this issue. I would comment, but I do not have the reputation to enter a comment, hence why I made another thread ([Why is Twilio not sending sms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624947/why-is-twilio-not-sending-sms))

Comment: I found this Blog Post from a //Build Conference. I implemented it and found I get a 401 Not Authorized error from the HTTP Request. Not sure what is going on, the SID and Auth Token work with the browser based example in the documentation, but does not work when I bypass the Library they distributed using Nuget and use the example from this blog post. [link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2011/09/using-the-twilio-rest-api-in-windows-8-metro-style-applications.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to get Twilio to work, this is not the answer to the technical issues (I think for some reason Twilio just has not authorized my account), but for those of you prototyping and need something asap I ended up using Plive and has a call and text message working within an hour. Here is my Sample code and it is actually cheaper than Twilio. I really like Twilio and have used it in the past, but never with C#. So maybe I can still get the issue resolved asap.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using RestSharp;
using Plivo.API;

namespace Plivo2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string auth_id = "MyAuthID";  // obtained from Plivo account dashboard
            string auth_token = "MyAuthTokey";  // obtained from Plivo account dashboard

            // Making a Call
            string from_number = "MyPliveNumber";
            string to_number = "TheNumberYouWantToContact";

            SendMessage(auth_id, auth_token,  from_number,  to_number,"Hello World!");

        }

        private static void CallPhone(string auth_id,string auth_token, string fromNumber, string toNumber){

            // Creating the Plivo Client
            RestAPI plivo = new RestAPI(auth_id, auth_token);

            IRestResponse<Call> response = plivo.make_call(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "from", fromNumber },
                { "to", toNumber }, 
                { "answer_url", "http://some.domain.com/answer/" }, 
                { "answer_method", "GET" }
            });

            // The "Outbound call" API response has four properties -
            // message, request_uuid, error, and api_id.
            // error - contains the error response sent back from the server.
            if (response.Data != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] proplist = response.Data.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in proplist)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(response.Data, null));
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine(response.ErrorMessage);

        }

        private static void SendMessage(string auth_id,string auth_token, string fromNumber, string toNumber, string message) { 

            RestAPI plivo = new RestAPI(auth_id, auth_token);

            IRestResponse<MessageResponse> resp = plivo.send_message(new Dictionary<string, string>() 
            {
                { "src", fromNumber },
                { "dst", toNumber },
                { "text", message },
                { "url", "http://some.domain/receivestatus/" },
                { "method", "GET" }
            });
            if (resp.Data != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] proplist = resp.Data.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in proplist)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(resp.Data, null));
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine(resp.ErrorMessage);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

The code you posted looks correct to me, but based on the Fiddler output it sounds like your getting an authentication error so I would double check that you've copy and pasted your account sid and auth token from  your Twilio account dashboard correctly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, I have copy and pasted it correctly. I am thinking maybe my account has not been activated yet or something. I made it a few days ago, but still the SID and AuthToken work in the browser based demo and not when I use them locally. I was actually hoping from a response from your @DevinRader, thanks for at least guaranteeing me that the code works. Now I know to focus on the SID and Token.

Comment: Just as a validation point, I am suppose to use the AccountSID and AuthToken Provided in my example or provided on this page correct? https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings

Comment: You should use the AccountSid and AuthToken from either here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account or the settings page: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings.  once you sign up you should not have to do anything else to start using your account.  We do not manually authorize accounts.  If your still having trouble, feel feee to send me an email devin [at] twilio [dot] com and I can look and see whats going on with your account.